# Yii update input field with wrong date outputed - where to control it?

Tags: datetime, yii

The user inserts a date like: 06/11/2012.

To insert into the database I use:

```
protected function beforeSave ()
{
  if($this->date <> '')
  { 
    list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $this->date);
    $mk=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
    $this->date = date ('Y-m-d', $mk);
  }

   return parent::beforeSave ();
}
```

**Question 1) Isn't there a shorter approach ?**

Anyway, it works, so I have a date in string format coming from the database date type field:

```
$date = '2012-11-06'
```

Then I use date format correctly, and I get the day and the month

```
yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd', $date);

yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('MMMM', $date);
```

All this seems to work fine. 
However, on my **update** form, I get a date like this:

> "20/12/1106"

On the form input field, the date should be converted to:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

when displayed.

On my model rules here's what I have:

```
array('date', 'type', 'type' => 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: Invalid Date!', 'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
```

**Where can we control this on Yii, so that on our input field of the date appears as dd/mm/yyyy ?**

I've done this, but ofcourse if we later have other controller then update, we have to change this. This seems NOT a good approach. :(

```
protected function afterFind ()
{
 if(Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'update')
 {
  if($this->date <> '')
  {
   Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDatetime($this->date,'short');
  }

  return parent::afterFind ();          
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little workout before rendering the update form. this should work but not tested
in your  **action Update** before `$this->render(....);`

```
$model->date = assign your required format here;
```

but if you need to keep this format you should avoid converting date at every place. Just save date in required format in database directly.

Comment: I have been adviced (all over this internet articles) to NOT save the date on other format then yyyy-mm-dd - it's the format the database accept, no fuss no muss. if we need to display it differently we convert it on the application. Date or Datetime are normally the fields here. I will give it a try. 3 min.

Comment: well you are saying it correct but i am sure for simple enough usage database would not reject the value :) you can set type varchar this would become only storage and may not help in quries

Comment: I've done it using afterFind(). But the approach is quite rude I believe. Can you please check it out.